# PHP: xpath replace content tag

Tags: php, xpath

I would like to change that content:

```
Cambio turno (FL) HMLN 16:00-20:00 del 08/09/2018 con (FL) HMLN 15:00-19:00 del 05/09/2018
```

into:

```
<a href="prova.it">Cambio turno (FL) HMLN 16:00-20:00 del 08/09/2018 con (FL) HMLN 15:00-19:00 del 05/09/2018</a>
```

This is an extract from the html page:

```
<td class="tdReset">
  <table id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_TblOperazioni_8529448" class="tblReset">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td operazione="accetta"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkAccetta_8529448" name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkAccetta_8529448" onclick="SelezioneUnivocaAccetta(this);AccettaRifiutaStessaRichiesta(this);" tabindex="0" type="checkbox"><label for="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkAccetta_8529448">Accetta</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td operazione="rifiuta">
          <input id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRifiuta_8529448" name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRifiuta_8529448" onclick="AccettaRifiutaStessaRichiesta(this);" tabindex="0" type="checkbox">
          <label for="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRifiuta_8529448">Rifiuta</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
<td>sab 01/09/2018</td>
<td>Proposta</td>
<td><span style="padding-left:15px;"> Jhon</span></td>
<td class="textWrap">Cambio turno (FL) HMLN 16:00-20:00 del 08/09/2018 con (FL) HMLN 15:00-19:00 del 05/09/2018</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

The code I created in PHP is as follows:

```
 $xpR=new DOMXPath( $dom_richieste_r );
  $operazione_select= $xpR->query( '//label[contains(.,"Accetta")]' );
  if( !empty( $operazione_select )){
    foreach( $operazione_select as $node2 ){
       //$node2->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->C14N(); // get Cambio turno (FL) HMLN 16:00-20:00 del 08/09/2018 con (FL) HMLN 15:00-19:00 del 05/09/2018 

       $newelement = $dom_richieste_r->createElement('a', 'prova'); 
       $newelement->setAttribute("href", "http://prova.it");
       $link_1=$node2->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->firstChild->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling->nextSibling;

      $link_1->replaceChild($newelement, $link_1);

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you have to select the node in question relative to the Accept button but you can do it with a single XPath query like this

```
//*[td/table/tbody/tr/td/label[contains(.,"Accetta")]]/td[5]
```

**[XPath Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Ctd%20class%3D%22tdReset%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20id%3D%22ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_TblOperazioni_8529448%22%20class%3D%22tblReset%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20operazione%3D%22accetta%22%3E%3Cinput%20id%3D%22ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkAccetta_8529448%22%20name%3D%22ctl00%24ctl00%24mainContent%24bodyContent%24chkAccetta_8529448%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onclick%3D%22SelezioneUnivocaAccetta(this)%3BAccettaRifiutaStessaRichiesta(this)%3B%22%20tabindex%3D%220%22%20type%3D%22checkbox%22%3E%3Clabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%3D%22ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkAccetta_8529448%22%3EAccetta%3C%2Flabel%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%20operazione%3D%22rifiuta%22%3E%3Cinput%20id%3D%22ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRifiuta_8529448%22%20name%3D%22ctl00%24ctl00%24mainContent%24bodyContent%24chkRifiuta_8529448%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onclick%3D%22AccettaRifiutaStessaRichiesta(this)%3B%22%20tabindex%3D%220%22%20type%3D%22checkbox%22%3E%3Clabel%20for%3D%22ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRifiuta_8529448%22%3ERifiuta%3C%2Flabel%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3Esab%2001%2F09%2F2018%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3EProposta%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3E%3Cspan%20style%3D%22padding-left%3A15px%3B%22%3E%20Jhon%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%20class%3D%22textWrap%22%3ECambio%20turno%20(FL)%20HMLN%2016%3A00-20%3A00%20del%2008%2F09%2F2018%20con%20(FL)%20HMLN%2015%3A00-19%3A00%20del%2005%2F09%2F2018%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E&=-&extract=%2F%2F*%5Btd%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr%2Ftd%2Flabel%5Bcontains(.%2C%22Accetta%22)%5D%5D%2Ftd%5B5%5D%0A&=%2F%2F*%5Btd%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr%2Ftd%2Flabel%5Bcontains(.%2C%22Accetta%22)%5D%5D%2Ftd%5B5%5D%0A&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)**

and then replace the inner text like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$operazione_select = $xpath->query('//*[td/table/tbody/tr/td/label[contains(.,"Accetta")]]/td[5]');
foreach ($operazione_select as $node) {
    //create link
    $newlink = $dom->createElement('a', $node->nodeValue);
    $newlink->setAttribute('href', 'http://prova.it');
    $node->removeChild($node->childNodes->item(0));
    $node->appendChild($newlink);    
}
```